# Adding an assembly to the GAC

Tags: gacutil

Somehow my GAC got messed up, System.Core.dll was unregistered or something. I don't have the win7 sdk so I can't just use gacutil. Is there some way I can add the single assembly to the gac? Or some way to download JUST gacutil?

Is the GAC stored in the registry? If so, where?

Thanks for the help, this is a pretty ugly bug.

Comment: You could download Visual Studio Express to get a new gacutil

Comment: I already have it, I've got VB, C#, and Web, but still no gacutil

Comment: These guys claim to have a gacutil to download. But it's not official so be careful. http://www.smartertools.com/Portal/KB/a22/troubleshooting-dll-initialization-routine-failed-file.aspx
You can find the link at point 3 of their error fix.

**Not posting this as an answer since the source of this gacutil is a third party website.**

Comment: I will take a look. The website has a good "safety" rating, so it is probably okay.

Answer (score 0):

The GAC is accessible trough this location: C:\Windows\assembly

This could help to install assemblies without using GACUtil: http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/powershell-install-gac-gacutil-for-powershell